# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 fails to return user claims in SAMLResponse for user from secondary user store

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml, claims, wso2-identity-server

I have this problem when using SAML SSO authentication. I have successfully set up WSO2IS 5.0.0 Identity server, I also succeeded setting up (at least I hope so) secondary user store. I used JDBCUserStoreManager implementation. I have set this store as DOMAIN. This user store works nice, at least I think it does. Because it is storing user attributes into its tables (USER_ATTRIBUTES) and those attributes are read by WSO2IS administration ...

```
https://localhost:9443/carbon/userprofile/edit.jsp?username=DOMAIN/demo_jbu&profile=default&fromUserMgt=true
```

Users are identified as DOMAIN\username so when I want to log in user from this DOMAIN, request goes to my AUTHENTICATOR implementation so I can manage authentication for users from this domain.

What is strange is, that if I use WSO2IS administration pages, I can set and read users's attributes well. And if I use SAML SSO authentication (have already set up service provider & claim mappings) for users from PRIMARY domain, everything goes fine and calling SP gets all attributes - mapped in WSO2IS administration here:

```
https://localhost:9443/carbon/application/configure-service-provider.jsp
```

If I use SAML SSO authentication, but I want to log user from my DOMAIN, SP doesn't get anything.

I can override this behavior in DefaultResponseBuilder, I can put into SAMLResponse anything I want, but I don't feel this approach is OK. Can anyone tell me, where to look for an error? What may be wrong? Where should I start looking for problems? I have already tried to debug it, and it seems it (SAML SSO/AUTHENTICATOR) doesn't find any claim for DOMAIN user.

Thank you in advance.

Josef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  this is bug in Identity Server 5.0.0.  When you are using SAML2 SSO, user can login to Identity Server with both username with domain name and username without domain name. Basically 
`bob`  and `foo.com/bob`  must both works and returns the `bob` user's attributes from `foo.com` user store.  However there is issue with IS 5.0.0, if secondary user store user login without domain name, Identity Server does not returns the user attributes. But, please try to login with `foo.com/bob` , Then it would return the user's attributes.

You can find the public [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2691).  It contains source diff. It must be a simple fix and you even can compile the source and add fix in to the Identity Server.

Comment: Hallo Asela,

It seems that this was the case. When we started using domain/user and added patch as you declared above (jira...), all started to work.

Thank you very much,

Josef

Comment: @Asela - I've used this (http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-read-saml-20-response-with.html) logic to get SAMLAssertion, but when I sending it ahead it's giving me {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid."}, even I don't see any exception's are coming... I've enabled logs, I 'm looking at wso2is-5.0.0/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
Could you please help ASAP?

Comment: Just checked and it seems the same problem exists with 5.1.0. The jira fix mentioned is not in the 5.1.0 source. Anyone experienced the same or is this a missing configuration?