# WSO2 Identity Server using a SAML IDP and a secondary user store - Attributes not set

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

We have the following Setup:

- WSO2 IS 5.1.0 configured with an external SAML IDP
- OAuth Service Providers configured against IS with outbound authentication against the external IDP
- IS has a secondary user store which is another external LDAP server

Login works and Just-In-Time provisioning to the secondary user store works as well. 
But it looks like user attributes and role memberships are not set for the user, when used with entitlements or userinfo endpoints.
It looks similar to what [wso2-identity-server-5-0-0-fails-to-return-user-claims-in-samlresponse-for-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850997/wso2-identity-server-5-0-0-fails-to-return-user-claims-in-samlresponse-for-user) describes. But the suggested fix is not working with 5.1.0.

Please note: the external IDP is returning the user as "username" not "userDomain/username". Is my configuration missing anything? Or is there a workaround? If the IDP does return the user with "userDomain/username" the attributes are set. Unfortunately the IDP cannot set this value for the user in production use.

Comment: You mean userinfo endpoint does not return claims as expected?

Comment: Yes, it only returns the user name and no attributes (the same as  if the user does not exist at all in the user store)

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the SP claim configurations, plus which grant type do you use to get the access token??

Comment: There is no special SP claim configuration. It works fine if the user logs in with local credentials (either with username or userDomain/username). If the user authenticates via external SAML IDP claims are not set. The flow from SP is as follows:  1. SP (OAuth - implicit) redirects to WSO2, 2. WSO2 displays login page, 3 User chooses external IDP, 4, User authenticated to external IDP and comes back to WSO2 with SAML assertion (nameid=username) 5. User gets redirected from WSO2 to OAuth SP, 6. OAuth SP vaildated token via SOAP request and retrieved claims